# Как определить количество подключений к сайту?

Tags: php

Как определить количество активных подключений на моем сайте? 
При заходе на сайт, давать тому, кто подключился, какой-то `id` и записывать в БД, а при выходе удалять?

Comment: А как вы хотите определять факт выхода?

Comment: Для каких целей вам это необходимо?

Comment: Да и под активными подключениями что подразумевается тоже не понятно.

Comment: @Bookin, чтобы выбрать два случайных пользователя и дать им возможность отсылать друг другу текст.сообщения. Чат.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю на php, без уловок специальных, Вы сможете только определить время последней активности, пользователя

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin Какими средствами уловить "онлайн" ?

Comment: @Sergey Alekseev, записывать время просмотра последней страницы, использовать php сессии (настроить на короткое время жизни например). Могу попробовать собрать все варианты в ответ. Вариант websockets использовать для чата не рассматриваете ?

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin ищу информацию по WebSockets. Но много чего не понимаю. Мне лишь ясно, что обмен между сервером проходит в реальном времени. Запросы посылаю с помощью JavaScript, а как их обрабатывать?

Comment: Конкретно php [есть на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/). Там и как самому сделать, и ссылки на фреймворки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47375/discussion-between-sergey-alekseev-and-evgenii-izhboldin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Вариант 1. Отслеживание последней активности.

  Ответ взял с [английской версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051895/whats-the-easiest-way-to-determine-if-a-user-is-online-php-mysql), автор @Sampson

  Всякий раз, когда пользователь получает доступ к странице, обновить поле последнего действия таблице `Users`. Затем сделать запрос (либо повесить задачу в `cron`) для всех пользователей, у кого была активность в течение последних 5 минут. Остальных перевести в статус `offline`.

  Если нужно знать что они активны, хотя и не уходят на другие страницы, то можно добавить что-то вроде пинга на `javascript`

  ```
  setInterval(function () {
       $.get("stillAlive.php");
  }, 60000); //60000 - 1 минута, можно свое время задать
  ```
- Вариант 2. Если необходимо точно отслеживать онлайн пользователей, используйте Websockets.

  Для php есть например [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/). В ней есть инструкция и как свой велосипед сделать, и ссылки на фреймворки.